# How to find the `img` tag with class name of `captcha` by combining use getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript

[image]

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("captcha");
```

By the above code line, the class names captcha can be found, but then how to filter the `img` tag out?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('img.captcha')

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("img.captcha")`

Answer (score 2):

Test the `tagName` of each one to see if it is an image or not:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("captcha");
const result = [...elements].filter( element => element.tagName === 'IMG' );
console.log(result[0]);
```

```html
<div class="captcha"></div>

<img class="captcha"></div>
```

However, it would be easier to just use `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` in the first place.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("img.captcha");
console.log(elements[0]);
```

```html
<div class="captcha"></div>

<img class="captcha"></div>
```